# how to optimize query in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I want to minimize this code:

```
if (empty(Input::get('channelName'))) {
    $channels = Channel::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->paginate($perPage)->setPath('?limit=' . $perPage);
} else {
    $channels = Channel::where('name', 'like', '%' . Input::get('channelName') . '%')->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->paginate($perPage)->setPath('?limit=' . $perPage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$channels = Channel::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->paginate($perPage)->setPath('?limit=' . $perPage);

    if (empty(Input::get('channelName'))) {
        $channels = $channels->get();
    } else {
        $channels = $channels->where('name', 'like', '%' . Input::get('channelName') . '%')->get();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries) is a cool "*thing*", because it allows you to chain methods you need. That gives the flexibility to append query statements depending on our needs.

```
$channelsQuery = Channel::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');
if (Input::has('channelName')) {
    $channelsQuery = $channelsQuery->where('name', 'like', '%' . Input::get('channelName') . '%');
}
$channels = $channelsQuery->paginate($perPage)->setPath('?limit=' . $perPage);
```

Also use `Input::has('channelName')` instead of just `empty(Input::get('channelName'))` in your if.